# SimpleBrowser encodeURI error page

Tags: php, uri

I'm trying to use the SimpleBrowser lib ([API doc](http://simpletest.org/api/SimpleTest/tutorial_Browser.pkg.html)) to simulate a task by clicking in a link and then post data. I already to this lib for another task and that works like a charm but i'm blocked in this one.

My goal is to click in "Reply" action to this ticket ([link](http://rt.easter-eggs.org/demos/4.2/Ticket/Display.html?id=924)), login: *admin* and pass: *admin* but when i use my code an error appear -> "No ticket specified". So i tried to debug this error and i realized that that the url is not good.

Normal link: http://rt.easter-eggs.org/demos/4.2/Ticket/Update.html?Action=Respond;id=924

Error link: http://rt.easter-eggs.org/demos/4.2/Ticket/Update.html?Action=Respond%3Bid%3D924

I suppose the error come from it but i'm not sure. If someone can help me with this issue please i will very appreciate it :)

```
require_once './simpletest/browser.php';


$browserRT = new SimpleBrowser();
$browserRT->useCookies();                                                                       
$browserRT->useFrames();                                                                        
$browserRT->get('http://rt.easter-eggs.org/demos/4.2/');                                       
$browserRT->setField('user', 'admin');                                                            
$browserRT->setField('pass', 'admin');                                                            

$browserRT->clickSubmit('Login');

$browserRT->addHeader('Referer: http://rt.easter-eggs.org/');                                   

$browserRT->get('http://rt.easter-eggs.org/demos/4.2/Ticket/Display.html?id=924');
$browserRT->clickLink('Reply');

echo $browserRT->getUrl();
```

echo result :
`http://rt.easter-eggs.org/demos/4.2/Ticket/Update.html?Action=Respond%3Bid%3D924`

With the above code you can try it, i hope someone can found a solution ^^ normaly if i echo `$browserRT->clickLink('Reply');` I should see the body of the ticket from response mode.

Thank you in advance for your help, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i found my issue, the problem come from '$browserRT->get('http://rt.easter-eggs.org/demos/4.2/Ticket/Display.html?id=924');'

I replaced the get by post ans that works good now.

Regards